# [META] How about a [WIKI] prefix?

Tags: meta, wiki

Like the meta-questions, how about using a [WIKI] prefix on community wiki "questions"?

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is users can search for wiki. And it doesn't use up one of the five-tags-per-question. I say yes!

Comment: agreed. Do it..